# Get value in foreach from array

Tags: php, arrays

How to get values from this array, which had std objects, using foreach?

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 28
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => Typ
        [FieldValue] => Panoramiczny
        ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 29
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => Producent
        [FieldValue] => sony
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 30
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => Model
        [FieldValue] => sony
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 31
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => Rok produkcji
        [FieldValue] => 1993
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 32
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => Nr seryjny
        [FieldValue] => sdadas
        )
    [5] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 33
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => Nr seryjny lampy
        [FieldValue] => sdadsd
        )
    [6] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 34
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => data2
        [FieldValue] => 05.08.2012
        )
    [7] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 35
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => Wyslij
        [FieldValue] => Wyślij
        ) 
    [8] => stdClass Object (
        [SubmissionValueId] => 36
        [FormId] => 3
        [SubmissionId] => 4
        [FieldName] => formId
        [FieldValue] => 3 
        ) 
    )
```

F.ex I need ['FieldName'] I tryed

```
 foreach ($wartosci as $value)
    { echo $value['FieldName'];}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

I got it, thanks to Grzegorz, here is solution:

```
foreach ($wartosci as $value)
        {
        echo $value->FieldName;
        }
```

Comment: Everyone knows where the php manual, no need to thanks for those

Answer (score 1):

Because it isn't an array object, but std object you can't call it with `$array['key']`

for an array variable.

```
foreach ($wartosci as $value)
    { echo $value['FieldName']; }
```

for a standard object.

```
foreach ($wartosci as $value)
    { echo $value->FieldName; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really search on the Internet first before asking developers to help you.

Here is the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I know where is manual, but is not simple array, it contains std objects, and thats why I don't know how to get it

Comment: @ariel: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875785/how-to-access-stdclass-object-after-a-specific-key-value-pair

Comment: @saleemahmed: Can you post an explanation why? Especially that Ariel did not object, upvoted me, mentioned me as the source of the answer, and this how this is done in stackoverflow?