# How to get json response in simple array

Tags: php, json

I created a script to get location against lat and long

```
$lat = '51.52682970000001';
$long = '-0.09787470000003395';


$url = 'http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?lon='.$long.'&lat='.$lat;

echo $get_live_data = file_get_contents($url);
echo "<pre>";
echo "<script>console.log(".$get_live_data.");</script>";
print_r($get_live_data);
```

That returns me data in this formate

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "result": [
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V     3AR",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 532081,
            "northings": 182577,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0974238437520936,
            "latitude": 51.5266670984233,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "3AR",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 36.142779048,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 3AT",
            "quality": 5,
            "eastings": 532081,
            "northings": 182577,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0974238437520936,
            "latitude": 51.5266670984233,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "3AT",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 36.142779048,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 8AZ",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 532081,
            "northings": 182577,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0974238437520936,
            "latitude": 51.5266670984233,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "8AZ",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 36.142779048,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 8BJ",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 532081,
            "northings": 182577,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0974238437520936,
            "latitude": 51.5266670984233,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "8BJ",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 36.142779048,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 8BU",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 532081,
            "northings": 182577,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0974238437520936,
            "latitude": 51.5266670984233,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "8BU",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 36.142779048,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 8BY",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 532062,
            "northings": 182635,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.097675844728179,
            "latitude": 51.5271927531582,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023B",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "8BY",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 42.685151811,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 3PA",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 532052,
            "northings": 182547,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0978528715183008,
            "latitude": 51.5264042809863,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "3PA",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 47.355650701,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 3PD",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 532045,
            "northings": 182544,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0979548407904613,
            "latitude": 51.5263789570549,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "3PD",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 50.456384882,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 3RG",
            "quality": 5,
            "eastings": 532099,
            "northings": 182579,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0971637753764948,
            "latitude": 51.5266808645084,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "3RG",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 52.042781777,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        },
        {
            "postcode": "EC1V 3QX",
            "quality": 1,
            "eastings": 531990,
            "northings": 182575,
            "country": "England",
            "nhs_ha": "London",
            "longitude": -0.0987355952757765,
            "latitude": 51.5266703846037,
            "parliamentary_constituency": "Islington South and Finsbury",
            "european_electoral_region": "London",
            "primary_care_trust": "Islington",
            "region": "London",
            "lsoa": "Islington 023C",
            "msoa": "Islington 023",
            "nuts": "Bunhill",
            "incode": "3QX",
            "outcode": "EC1V",
            "distance": 62.319878004,
            "admin_district": "Islington",
            "parish": "Islington, unparished area",
            "admin_county": null,
            "admin_ward": "Bunhill",
            "ccg": "NHS Islington",
            "codes": {
                "admin_district": "E09000019",
                "admin_county": "E99999999",
                "admin_ward": "E05000367",
                "parish": "E43000209",
                "ccg": "E38000088"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to get postcodes in variable like, 
$postcode1 = EC1V 3AR, 
$postcode2 = EC1V XVG
and so on..

Comment: $decodeanswer = json_decode(result); You can Decode json Format by this                                      Then You CAn Echo variable like this $decodeanswer['result']['postcode']

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it helped me out, can you please further explain me that how to get exact post code variable ?

Comment: stdClass Object
    (
    [status] => 200
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [postcode] => AB10 1XG

Comment: what is stdClass ? how can I approact [status] ?

Comment: Yupppeee !!! I have found the solution
I just need to convert it into array
$value = get_object_vars($decodedvaluel);
$val =  $value['result']['0']['postcodes'];

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875785/how-to-access-stdclass-object-after-a-specific-key-value-pair