# How to change value in array objects?

Tags: arrays, object

I had query for data in this SQL:

```
//query by location total post
$sql = 'SELECT ljj.job_id, count(ljj.job_id) as count, ljj.job_type FROM {local_jobs_job} ljj INNER JOIN {local_jobs_location} ljl ON ljj.job_location = ljl.location_id GROUP BY ljj.job_type';


//get the query into record
$data = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

The output is here:

```
Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [job_id] => 1 [count] => 8 [job_type] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [job_id] => 3 [count] => 7 [job_type] => 1 ) )
```

I need to change the value of:

```
[job_type] => 0 to [job_type] => 'Job' 
[job_type] => 1 to [job_type] => 'Internship'
```

I do not know how to get to the value as it is an object array.

How to get the value and replace it?

Comment: You find here a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875785/how-to-access-stdclass-object-after-a-specific-key-value-pair

Comment: Could you give an example for my question? I do read your reference but still having problem. I'm not very good in multi arrays. Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Sorry about time i was away few minutes example here ;), regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a complet based on your example :
So you got some **3 arrays** in the ouput the *first array* add *2 childs object* **index 1, 3** the *childs object* got **one array with 3 index** literals (**job_id, count, job_type**) so **array = []** and **object = {}**

So i **cast** to object **(object)** the **2 childs arrays** and **transform** to an object to being a **stdclass object** as your example getting from database.

```
<?php
//Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [job_id] => 1 [count] => 8 [job_type] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [job_id] => 3 [count] => 7 [job_type] => 1 ) );

$data = Array( 1=>(object)Array("job_id" => 1, "count" => 8, "job_type" => 0), 3 => (object)Array("job_id" => 3, "count" => 7, "job_type" => 1));


var_dump($data); // show your ouput

var_dump($data[1]->{'job_type'}); // index 1 to object attribute job_type = we got the value  "0"
var_dump($data[3]->{'job_id'}); // index 3 to object attribute job_type = value = "1"

//to change you have to affect your value so :
$data[1]->{'job_type'} = "Job";
$data[3]->{'job_type'} = "Internship";

var_dump($data[1]->{'job_type'}); // index 1 to object attribute job_type = we got the value  "job"
var_dump($data[3]->{'job_type'}); // index 3 to object attribute job_type = value = "Internship"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @headmax for you help and guidance. You save my day. Your answer works and I can change the value inside the object. And I also can understand better on multi arrays and objects. Many thanks to you.

Comment: @joun Welcome joun ;) have a nice day.

Comment: 'thumbs up' :). Have a nice day too