# Access object property which is a number

Tags: php

I have object:

```
object(stdClass)#6 (4) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { 
                ["name"]=> string(3) "Jan" 
                ["job"]=> string(2) "IT" 
            } 
        [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { 
                ["name"]=> string(4) "Adam" 
                ["job"]=> string(2) "PR" 
            } 
        [2]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { 
                ["name"]=> string(6) "Wojtek" 
                ["job"]=> string(2) "IT" 
            } 
        [3]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
                ["name"]=> string(6) "Marcin"
                ["job"]=> string(3) "Car" 
            }
    }
```

My problem is: how I can use this object:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (2) { 
        ["name"]=> string(3) "Jan" 
        ["job"]=> string(2) "IT" 
    }
```

This object is in class.

Something like this: `$this->object->object` or `$this->object->0` does not work.

But when I change index number for example: "0" or "1" to "A" or "B" it works

Comment: this seems like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875785/how-to-access-stdclass-object-after-a-specific-key-value-pair#answer-15094521) so try `$this->{'0'}->name`

Comment: try this `echo $this->variable->{0};`

Comment: If you get the object from `json_decode`, you should think about using the second param `json_decode($json, true)`

Comment: Thanks, @AlexandrePainchaud, I don't user array. Rendi, 
your way is not working, Philipp, I don't use json

Comment: @grzeso glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert multiple arrays to an object with the following code:

```
$obj1 = (object) ['name' => 'Jan', 'job' => 'IT'];
$obj2 = (object) ['name' => 'Adam', 'job' => 'PR'];
$obj3 = (object) ['name'=> 'Wojtek', 'job' => 'IT'];
$obj4 = (object) ['name' => 'Marcin', 'job' => 'Car'];
$obj = (object) [$obj1, $obj2, $obj3, $obj4];
```

To get the `name` of the first object you can cast the object to an array (solution for PHP < 7.2):

```
echo ((array) $obj)[0]->name; // Jan
echo ((array) $obj)[1]->name; // Adam
```

Since PHP 7.2 you can also access numeric property names too:

```
echo $obj->{0}->name; // Jan
echo $obj->{1}->name; // Adam
```

---

**complete example (with demo):**

```
$obj1 = (object) ['name' => 'Jan', 'job' => 'IT'];
$obj2 = (object) ['name' => 'Adam', 'job' => 'PR'];
$obj3 = (object) ['name'=> 'Wojtek', 'job' => 'IT'];
$obj4 = (object) ['name' => 'Marcin', 'job' => 'Car'];
$obj = (object) [$obj1, $obj2, $obj3, $obj4];

//your output
var_dump($obj);

//PHP < 7.2: get the output of the name of the first object.
echo 'Test: '.((array) $obj)[0]->name; // Jan

//or since PHP 7.2
echo $obj->{0}->name; // Jan
```

> **demo:** https://3v4l.org/kIVuS

Comment: @grzeso - Yes I see (already updated) but describe how you get the object too.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for your answer, but I create object in other way: `$obj1 = (object) ['name'=>'Jan','job'=>'IT'];$obj2 = (object) ['name'=>'Adam','job'=>'PR'];$obj3 = (object) ['name'=>'Wojtek','job'=>'IT'];$obj4 = (object) ['name'=>'Marcin','job'=>'Car'];$obj = (object) [$obj1, $obj2, $obj3, $obj4];`

Comment: Sebastian, thank you very much. I agree with you, it works diferent on PHP < 7.2 and PHP >7.2. I changed PHP Version on my laptop and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Object properties whose names are numbers are actually invalid. That they can be created from certain operations is a long-standing bug.

This bug was finally fixed in PHP 7.2; the [7.2.0 changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.0) lists several bug reports which are fixed by this change, and links to [the RFC which proposed the new behaviour](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/convert_numeric_keys_in_object_array_casts).

You can see the difference [in this demo](https://3v4l.org/tfbH0):

```
$obj = (object)[1,2,3];

var_dump($obj);
var_dump($obj->{"0"});
```

Prior to PHP 7.2, this produces an object like the one you have, and the property cannot be accessed:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$0 in /in/tfbH0 on line 6
NULL
```

After 7.2, it produces a subtly different object, where the property names are all strings rather than integers, and can be accessed with the `->{"name"}` syntax:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["0"]=>
  int(1)
  ["1"]=>
  int(2)
  ["2"]=>
  int(3)
}
int(1)
```

If you can't upgrade your PHP, the only workarounds I know of are:

- Don't convert arrays with numeric keys to objects; just keep them as arrays.
- If you are passed such an object by code you can't control, cast it back to an array, with `(array)$object`.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I didn't know about this problem.